# Live streaming on web with a .ts stream url

Tags: streaming, rtmp

When i try to stream this url with a webplayer on my web page
http://proiptv.505x.biz:8000/live/133/165848/104.ts 
its not dispalying but he is downloading the stream. 
How can i convert this to a rtmp stream or play it on the web

Answer (score 4):

You need to transcode the original live MPEG-2 Transport Stream to a format suitable for web.

For RTMP you can use the open-source tool **ffmpeg**:

`ffmpeg -i http://proiptv.505x.biz:8000/live/133/165848/104.ts -f flv rtmp://your_server/`

There are a lot free or paid tools that allow you to re-stream MPEG-TS (Nimble Streamer, Wowza Streaming Engine, the RTMP module for the nginx web server, ffserver from the ffmpeg tools and many more).

To play the resulting stream on the web there are a variety of free or paid players like Video.js, mediaelement.js, JWPlayer, Flowplayer.